# How to prevent the reference to the library from becoming a reference to a more advanced version

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

First of all I apologize for my English, I use google translate.

I have an `ms access` project that contains a reference to the `PowerPoint 14.0 library`, I develop it in `Office 2010`.

I recently had a case where one of the clients opened the file in Office 2013 or 2016 and then the reference was automatically changed to the `PowerPoint 16.0 library`, then he opened the file again in Office 2010 and got the "Missing reference" error, since Office 2010 does not have the Power Point 16.0 library.

The question is: Is there a way to prevent the reference from becoming a 16.0 library, and to make it always remain a reference to the 14.0 library, even if the office version is more advanced than 2010.

I know you can use late binding using the `CreateObject` method and avoid the references altogether, but I'd rather find a way to keep the reference because the project has a lot of constants from the PowerPoint library.